# Suppose that $v_1,...,v_m$ is a list in $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $v_1,...,v_m$ is a list in $V$. What can be said of the list if $v_j \in span(v_1,....,v_{j-1})$, for some $1 \leq j \leq n$? What happens to the span if $v_j$ is removed from the list?

not sure what would be an answer for the first question but i think if $v_j$ is removed then the list would still be equal.

Comment: You are correct that $v_j$ can be removed from the list without changing the $\text{Span}$. That's because the list is one of linearly dependent vectors, as $v_j\in\text{Span}(v_1,\ldots,v_{j-1})$ means that $v_j$ can be obtained by a linear combination of the vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_{j-1}$. So, $v_j$ is redundant in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the first question, we can say that the vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_m$ are not linearly independent. As for the second, the span is not changed.

Answer (score 1):

If $v_j\in span\{v_1,...,v_{j-1}\}$, then we know that $v_1,...,v_m$ are not linearly independent and therefore are not a basis for $V$.

You are correct: if $v_j$ is removed from the list, then the span would still be equal (though the list itself would have one fewer element, so you may want to check your wording).